# Laravel 8 error. Missing Parameters in URL

Tags: php, http-post, laravel-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0M0b.png)Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: product_update] [URI: product-update/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\productedit.blade.php)

I have already provided the parameter via route but still, there is an error.

Code Screenshots are below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlMg9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt7GP.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEcOR.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this

```
route('product_update', ['id' => $productID])
```

I hope it's helpful

Comment: Ahmad  sir but if i do that then it will only for the "id" which is 1.

Comment: @AamirAnwar just placeholder replace the id with your product id off course